# Include SVG file in SVG

Tags: include, svg

I've got a linearGradient in the defs section of my SVG file, and reference it with fill="url(#myGradientName)".  That works great so far.

I think I should be able to put my whole defs section in its own SVG file, and then just reference that from all my SVG images.  That is, something like:

styles.svg:

```
<svg xmlns=...>
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="myGradient" ...>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

image.svg:

```
<svg xmlns=...>
  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="styles.svg#myGradient"/>
</svg>
```

But I can't seem to get the style to apply.  Do I have the wrong syntax for IDs external to this file (styles.svg#myGradient)?  Do I need to explicitly include the file first somehow?

I've been pouring over the SVG spec and it looks like this should be possible, but none of the examples actually show it being done.

Edit: The [FOP FAQ](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/faq.html#svg-url) suggests that the correct syntax is fill="url(grad.svg#PurpleToWhite)", but that doesn't work in Gecko or Webkit.  Is that correct and nobody supports it, or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20459685/how-do-i-use-svg-patterns-in-a-cross-browser-consistent-way

Answer (score 4):

It looks like this is only supported under [Firefox 3.1](https://developer.mozilla.org/web-tech/2008/10/10/svg-external-document-references/).

Comment: Any infos about Opera or Webkit/Safari/Chrome?

Comment: The question mentioned that it doesn't work in Webkit.  I haven't tried this in Opera, but Gecko seems to have the most featureful SVG support in other areas, so I'd be surprised if Opera (and nobody else) supported that.

Comment: [This Webkit Bug shows](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12499) that this incorrect behavior is still unresolved in even current builds of Chrome/Safari.  Lots of bitching on the long-lived fix report, yet the issue is **unresolved** and the last maintainer quit the project due to a conflict of interest..  Great...

Answer (score 3):

You do need to say `fill="url(styles.svg#myGradient)"`. That works in Firefox 4 beta 6 and I imagine it worked in Firefox 3.5. But Chrome (7.0.517.41 beta) and the IE9 beta (9.0.7930.16406) still do not support this. It looks like they both look for #myGradient in the current document instead of actually going to the specified URL. Gross.

Here are the complete files I used to test this:

styles.svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="myGradient">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="red" />
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="black" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

image.svg

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(styles.svg#myGradient)"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: You COULD do that, but that would mean your gradient would be specified inline to the SVG document. What if you wanted different gradients on multiple repetitions of the same SVG icon?

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo That sounds like a different question. I don’t know the answer offhand. Maybe [`fill="currentColor"`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/painting.html#SpecifyingPaint) would help. If you’re including an SVG icon repeatedly using `<img>` or `<object>` then [it won’t inherit CSS properties from the page’s stylesheets](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/styling.html#Inheritance) but maybe `currentColor` would still work.

Comment: An 2014 update: Tested OK in Firefox but the gradient is not found (rendered black) in Chrome. Sadly ruins the whole "include a styles.svg" concept. 

An alternative would be to include those "defs" serve-side.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the FOP FAQ is right, the correct syntax is embracing the URI with `url(...)`. Just checked with my Firefox, and it handles fills *only* with surrounding `url()`. It would be a bug in Safari or Opera, if the'd handle it differently.

I coincidentally filed a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1104024/gradient-servers-as-external-files-in-svg), but with similarly little success.

Cheers,