# Gradient servers as external files in SVG

Tags: css, url, svg, external, gradient

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Include SVG file in SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652004/include-svg-file-in-svg)

the fill property in SVG accepts an url to point to a gradient/pattern element, an instance of a so-called 'paint server'.

**The Question:** Is it possible in *any* browser (that is, not IE, of course), to use a gradient defined in an external SVG file? Like, in `rect.svg`,

```
<rect fill="url(grad.svg#my_grad)" />
```

and the corresponding `<linearGradient />` element in `grad.svg`?

It would be really nice, because then one could store all his gradients/patterns in one file and get that cached...

Cheers,

**Update:** This question is, by its meaning, a duplicate of [Include SVG file in SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652004/include-svg-file-in-svg) (where the question was answered for at least Firefox). I keep mine open, because I think the title and tags are more likely to get found by, well, you.

Comment: do you need to specifically use the SVG file in a browser, or should it also work for a SVG edit (inkscape, for example).
Because, if it's only a browser-related question, it is still possible to load the SVG containing the patterns/gradients definitions and insert it in the DOM, so as the url() refers to a local id

Comment: I know, from painful experience, that it doesn't work in Inkscape. But actually, at the moment I'm interested more in browser support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SVG Specification just states that you can use an URI - so it should be possible. Browser Support is of course a different matter.

I just wrote and tested a little sample file.

It doesn't work in Inkscape - but it does work with the Apache Batik Toolkit.

For Browser Support, i uploaded the file to [browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org/) and to summarize it: some browsers do support external gradients - some don't.
e.g.:

- Firefox 3.0 NO
- Firefox 3.5 YES
- Opera 9.64, 10.0 YES
- Safari 4 NO
- Chrome 2.0 NO

Comment: Cool, thanks! I should think more regularly of browsershots.org...

Comment: Any progress on this in Chrome in 2021?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, change the url to

```
<rect fill="url(grad.svg?param=my_grad" />
```

And then generate the svg dynamically?

Comment: Nope. The problem is, that currently browsers only resolve fragment identifiers in a `fill="url(..)"`, that is, urls starting with "#", and not full uris. That has nothing to do with dynamic generation, but is a problem to *access* and external file overall.